# JFrame.setBounds not working with small values

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Here is the constructor for a small class I have that inherits from JFrame:

```
public ToolView(Controller controller) {
    super("Tools");
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(10, 100, 110, 800);
    setResizable(false);

    final BaseTool[] tools = {new MoveTool()};
    for(int i=0; i<tools.length; i++) {
        tools[i].setBounds(2, 2 + i * 50, 50, 50);
        add(tools[i]);
    }

    setVisible(true);
}
```

In the setBounds method, I would like to be able to set the width of the window to around 60. The shown code indicates 110. Values less than around 120 seem to display a window size of around 120. How can I get the window to be skinnier?

Comment: `setBounds`  Stop that nonsense and use layouts.

Comment: It's a very basic window. Just a column of the tools in the `tools` array.

Comment: All frames have a "minimum" size that the OS will allow them to be resized to.  This prevents the icon, min, max and close buttons from running over each other.  Nothing you can do about...

Comment: @Greg So a simple layout manager, like `GridLayout` should be suitable...

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get window to be skinnier?

Make it [undecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29).

Comment: I would like to keep the title and close buttons.

Comment: *"I would like to keep the title and close buttons"*  Where do you expect those to be displayed when the frame is very thin?  You can't have your cake, and eat it too..

Comment: Why are those values in a column instead of a row?  What is this GUI for?